Does Google Chrome (Desktop) have a Read Aloud Feature Similar to Microsoft Edge?
I hate using Microsoft Edge but its's built-in "Read Aloud" feature is pretty good, i prefer using Chrome as my main browser and would love to know if Chrome has anything similar?

I am sure there is an extension that might exist but you do understand that Edge and Chrome are both upon Chromium, right?

“built” upon not “both”…

Read aloud

There are no sources I would be familiar recommending. In 2024 your limited to torrents and then verifying the checksums. All other sources directly from Microsoft were taken down once Windows 7 officially ended support earlier this year.

thanks heaps @Ramhound
